# I'm converting existing SCSS code to JSS, I'm stuck at converting the following nested classes

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jss

I'm attaching the code for SCSS and react elements below

```css
.chatPane {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  .form-control, .form-control:focus, .form-control:active {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
render() {
    const { isLoaded, messages, handleSendMessage, user } = this.props;
    const dialogChildren = (
      <div className="modalBox">
        <h1 className="modalBox-header">Join chat</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onCreateUser}>
          <input className="modalBox-input" placeholder="Type your name" onChange={this.onNameChange} />
          <hr className="modalBox-horizontal"/>
          <div className="modalFooter">
            <Link className="modalBox-link" to="/chat">close</Link>
            <button className="modalBox-button" onClick={this.onCreateUser} type="submit">join</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
```

I want some help in converting this code into JSS

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: We definitely need more information to be able to help you; specifically what in your JSX do you want to have those classes? Do you want the modalBox-input to get it?

Answer (score 1):

You need default presets or particularly jss-nested plugin, which replaces & with the parent rule selector.

```
{
  a: {
    '& .b, & .c:focus, & .d:focus': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you need all selectors global, which is a bad idea, you can use jss-global plugin (also part of default preset)

```
'@global': {
  '.a': {
    color: 'green',
    '& .b, & .c:focus, & .d:focus': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to convert this or would each class need to be declared seaperatly? h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #1a3c8a;
  font-weight: 300;
}